# What counts as a read in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

What counts as a read in Firestore:

```
db.collection("Collection").document(id).get()
```

OR:

```
db.collection("Collection").document(id).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
 task.result.get("field")
 task.result.get("field")
 task.result.get("field")
 task.result.get("field")
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how many fields you're reading, you'll only have to pay a single read.

Answer (score 2):

Both. You are calling `.get()` method so that makes a call to Firestore servers (if offline persistence is not enabled or document is not found in cache). Just creating the `DocumentReference` however does not charge:

```
// just a reference, document data not fetched
db.collection("Collection").document(id)
```

In the 2nd code snippet, the `task.result` seems to be fetched data and you are just read a single field locally.

Comment: That is, if I call .get () 10 times in the second variant, then this will be considered one reading?

Comment: @TriangleN if you are referring to `get()` on `task.result` then no, you can call it as man times you want that'll be 1 read only. You are only charged for the get() on DocumentReference that fetches data from Firestore server.

Comment: Every time you call `get()` on a document reference, it reads the document from/on the server ad thus charges you for one document-read. Calling `get("field name")` on a document snapshot is a pure client-side operation that does not require reading the document from/on the server, and thus does not charge you for a document-read.